# Overlapping table of figure (and tables) label when running auctex from a non master file

Tags: auctex, reftex-mode

The problem is: When I run C-c C-a (TeX-command-run-all) from the master file it goes well and produce the following output,

[image]

but then, when I edit other .tex file (abstract.tex for instance) and run again C-C C-a, it asks for setting the master file and everything goes smoothly except it renders the following result for the list of figures (and tables as well):
[image]

Even if I undo the changes made, I cannot obtain the correct rendering again.

It seems to be a problem with auctex handling multiple files.

My question is: What does auctex do differently when running from a non-master file and if there is a solution for this overlapping label problem.

Comment: The answer to your question is "nothing" (or, at least, it shouldn't do anything different, otherwise I'd consider it a bug).  Having the real code to test with would be great, if we have a recipe to reproduce your problem we can try to find the culprit, if present.

Comment: I figured it out, It was a package called `subfig` apparently. When I removed it from the preamble everything worked fine.